# Using DDL to create a Foreign Key, with Delphi

Tags: delphi-7, ddl

I am using Delphi 7 to create an Access DB with some DDL statements. It's going to be a relatively simple relational database for a simple stock invoice system. I've managed to create a table called CUSTOMER no problem, but on trying to create a table called ORDER, where in ORDER i have a foreign key field CustomerID, i get the following error message:

> "Syntax error in field definition".

CustomerID is the Key field in the CUSTOMER table and I simply want to link the two together. Here is my DDL statements for both.

```
cs:= 'CREATE TABLE tblCUSTOMER ('+
      'CustomerID Number,' +
      'FName Text(20),' +
      'SName Text(20),' +
      'AddressLine1 Text(35))';
ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;

cs:='CREATE INDEX idxCustomerID ON tblCUSTOMER (CustomerID) WITH PRIMARY';
ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;

cs:= 'CREATE TABLE tblORDER ('+
'OrderID Number,'+
//Here is the line!!
'CustomerID Number CONSTRAINT CustomerID REFERENCES tblCUSTOMER (CustomerID),'+
'OrderDate DateTime,'+
'CREATE INDEX idxPrimary ON tblORDER (OrderID) WITH PRIMARY)';
ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

I'm guessing the issue is something with the foreign key declaration above. What have I done wrong please?

I have also tried this:

```
cs:= 'CREATE TABLE tblORDER ('+
'OrderID Number CONSTRAINT PK_OrderID PRIMARY KEY,'+
'CustomerID Number CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID REFERENCES tblCUSTOMER (CustomerID),'+
'OrderDate DateTime,'+
'CREATE INDEX idxPrimary ON tblORDER (OrderID) WITH PRIMARY';
```

Still not working.

Comment: In examples shown at this link, the identifier after CONSTRAINT needs to be the name of the constraint itself.  CustomerID number constraint FK_MYCONSTRAINTNAME references ...   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243835(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Tried that... see my edit above.

Comment: Are you sure it's the foreign key causing the problem?  Perhaps it's the index definition, or something else.  Perhaps try to create a table with just the foreign key and nothing else.  By the way, the last example has no closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  The CONSTRAINT clause should have went as follows:

```
cs:= 'CREATE TABLE tblORDER ('+
'OrderID Number,'+
'CustomerID Number CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID References tblCUSTOMER (CustomerID),' +
'OrderDate DateTime)';
ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

And the CREATE INDEX Clause should have been a separate DDL command.

```
cs:='CREATE INDEX idxOrderID ON tblORDER (OrderID) WITH PRIMARY';
ADOCommand1.CommandText:=cs;
ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

Thanks anyway